# Vertical centering with a subway tile backsplash

Tags: tile

People always talk about horizontal spacing , but I never hear much about vertical.  I'm installing 3X6 subway tile today in an area with a vertical spacing between the cabinet and the counter lip of 15 1/8".  Should I be cutting a quarter inch off the tops and bottoms so I get three full tiles in the center and 3/4 of a tile at the top and bottom, or should I just start with full tiles at the bottom?

Comment: Definitely lay it out to eliminate thin strips by cutting top and bottom. The closer to "full tile" you can get, the better it will look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is verging on "close as opinion based," but I'd use a full tile on the bottom, since you rarely, if ever, see the top tile under the cabinet, unless you are just barely taller than counter height, or lying on the floor. The one just above the counter you see all the time if you are of normal height and standing/sitting.

I have also been known to choose a border/trim of a smaller tile to make less fussy cutting and an accent feature for short people or those lying on the floor.